# Finding position information of repeated characters in string

Tags: string, r, text-mining

I have a DNA sequence that I'm trying to determine the quality of the assembly by visualizing the presence and frequency of n (generic nucleotides). I can do this by putting it into a specific format and loading it into some other software.

The output would be tsv/csv with the following column names: startposition endposition value(end-start)

My first thought was to create a vector of characters from the string and then loop through recording the start and stop positions of a block of n's. It works, but I'm almost certain there is a better and easier way. I'm not very good with regex, but willing to use it with some help.

```
stringa<-"attaaatagccgcggaagacctttttcatatgatagaatccccaacacannnnnnacgtagacaeagagaagattttcccccggagagcgcgaatagannnnnnnnnccataatatttataaattaatttat"
stringvector<-strsplit(stringa, NULL)[[1]]

newdf<-data.frame(start=rep(NA, 10), end=rep(NA, 10), length=rep(NA, 10))
counter=1

for (i in 1:length(stringvector)){
    if (stringvector[i]=="n"){
        if (is.na(newdf[counter,][1])){
                #record start position
                newdf[counter,][1]<-i
        } else {
            #do nothing you found the start already
        }
    }
    if (stringvector[i]!="n" & !is.na(newdf[counter,][1]) & is.na(newdf[counter,][2])){
        newdf[counter,][2]<-i-1
        newdf[counter,][3]<-newdf[counter,][2]-newdf[counter,][1]
        counter=counter+1
    }
}
```

The sequence lengths should not be bigger than about 50 million characters and I don't need to do this for many sequences, but was hoping for something more elegant.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should award the answer to @Henrik. He took the trouble to benchmark solutions, and suggested the fastest too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility using the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
m <- stri_locate_all(str = "annaannn", regex = "n+")[[1]]
length <- m[ , "end"] - m[ , "start"] + 1
cbind(m, length)
#      start end length
# [1,]     2   3      2
# [2,]     6   8      3
```

**Edit:** Added benchmark. `stri_locate_all` seems fastest. Please note that I added an "end" variable to @ilir's answer to make it more comparable to the other two alternatives.

```
fun_stri <- function(x){
  m <- stri_locate_all(str = x, regex = "n+")[[1]]
  length <- m[ , "end"] - m[ , "start"] + 1
  cbind(m, length)
}

fun_greg <- function(x){
  result <- gregexpr(pattern="n+", c(x))[[1]]
  data.frame(start = result,
             end = result + attr(result, "match.length") - 1,
             length = attr(result, "match.length"))
}

fun_rle <- function(stringa, char = "n") { 
  tmp <- rle(strsplit(stringa, NULL)[[1]])
  start <- sapply(which(tmp$values == char)-1, function(x) sum(tmp$length[1:x]))+1 
  length <- tmp$length[tmp$values == char]
  return(data.frame(start, end = start + length, length))
}

# just check results on short strings
fun_stri("annaannn")
fun_greg("annaannn")
fun_rle("annaannn")

fun_stri(stringa)
fun_greg(stringa)
fun_rle(stringa) 

library(microbenchmark)

# size = 1e4
x <- paste(sample(c("a", "t", "c", "g", "n"), size = 1e4, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
microbenchmark(
  fun_stri(x),
  fun_greg(x),
  fun_rle(x),
  times = 10)

# Unit: microseconds
#        expr       min        lq     median        uq       max neval
# fun_stri(x)   535.221   574.753   632.9140   684.611   711.980    10
# fun_greg(x)   709.699   748.473   776.9815   790.286   913.068    10
#  fun_rle(x) 47588.602 48281.955 50071.7875 67811.410 87781.053    10

# size = 1e5 
x <- paste(sample(c("a", "t", "c", "g", "n"), 1e5, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
microbenchmark(
  fun_stri(x),
  fun_greg(x),
  fun_rle(x),
  times = 10)

# Unit: milliseconds
#        expr         min          lq      median          uq         max neval
# fun_stri(x)    2.871487    2.963478    3.011184    3.202578    3.272142    10
# fun_greg(x)    4.842070    4.914295    5.013888    5.368927    5.490949    10
#  fun_rle(x) 3853.887170 3868.795788 3889.699217 4228.450830 4411.025536    10

# size = 5e7 ("about 50 million characters" in OP)
x <- paste(sample(c("a", "t", "c", "g", "n"), size = 5e7, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
microbenchmark(
  fun_stri(x),
  fun_greg(x),
  times = 10)

# Unit: seconds
#        expr      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
# fun_stri(x) 1.479089 1.54405 1.606676 1.757292 1.974795    10
# fun_greg(x) 2.381448 2.39754 2.422554 2.476974 2.643259    10
```

Comment: @bhive01, I added some benchmarks for longer strings.

Comment: Wow, that `stringi` thing is fast. What's behind it?

Comment: Pure C++ :) Like every function in this package.

Comment: When I stumbled over `stringi` the first time, I think it was my `base` regex answer being 'beaten' by an equivalent (at least to my regex ignorant eyes) `stringi` answer. They mentioned it was written in C++. Well, for a more accurate answer you better check the [**stringi site**](http://docs.rexamine.com/R-man/stringi/stringi-package.html)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if more elegant, but should certainly be faster if you use `gregexpr`.

```
result <- gregexpr(pattern="n+", c(stringa))[[1]]
new.df <- data.frame(start=result, length=attr(result, "match.length"))
```

Note that this solution also needs just minor modification if `stringa` is a vector. In that case `gregexpr` will return a list that needs to be unpacked. It can be done without a loop, with a combination of `lapply` and `do.call(rbind,...)`

Comment: It's a shame I can't accept more than one answer. I like the fact that I don't have to copy the string into a vector and can leave it as is. Thanks very much.

Comment: +1, very nice indeed! I took the liberty to add an "end" variable to your code for the benchmark in my answer.

Comment: I thought that perhaps it was `data.frame` (you) vs. `matrix` (me) that could explain part of the speed difference between our answers, but when I tried a matrix version of your code it didn't change so much.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks. I don't think there should be a big difference with `data.frame` anymore with 3.1.0, especially because we are only creating it once.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
rle_ <- function(stringa, char = "n") { 
  tmp <- rle(strsplit(stringa, NULL)[[1]])
  start <- sapply(which(tmp$values == char)-1, function(x) sum(tmp$length[1:x]))+1 
  length <- tmp$length[tmp$values == char]
  return(data.frame(start, end = start + length, length))
}
rle_(stringa)
# start end length
# 1    50  56      6
# 2    99 108      9
```

Comment: Need to change length<- a$length... to tmp$length. Otherwise, much shorter and clearer. Hadn't come across rle before. Very nice.

Comment: @lukeA, Doesn't the "n chunks" start at 55 and 99?

Comment: @Henrik, I got 50 and 99 as the start points from my method and yours. Something's not quite right then. The length of values is 83, while the length of the vector is 132. I guess it's combining them all when there are repeats. Probably need to add up the values from values[1]:values[=="n"] to get 50 and then 90.

Comment: @Henrik oh my, you're right. I misunderstood `rle`. @ilir's regex solution is the way to go. With rle and w/out regex it get's ugly...